# Python Module Permissions

Tags: python, linux, eclipse

I installed a python library in Linux, but my script could not find this module. I noticed that it got installed with root as owner.  Once I changed the owner to my user then the script worked fine. What should I change the permissions to so all users have access to the library (I'm assuming I should change the owner to root)?  Is there a way to recursively set  permissions only for files or only for directories?

Also, for some reason in Eclipse the library import statements have "Unresolved import" messages even though I'm able to execute the script without a problem.  If I use a local copy of the library instead, then the messages go away.

Comment: chown user -R directory. Will set a directory's permissions recursively. Can't help you with Eclipse though... that's a nightmare for python

Answer (score 7):

Leave the owner alone, but make the modules all world-readable. Directories should be executable, so people can list their contents. `chmod` itself can't automatically distinguish normal files from directories, but `find` can, so combine them.

On a typical Linux machine using Python 2.7, this is how you'd do it (as root):

```
find /usr/lib/python2.7 -type f -exec chmod a+r {} \;
find /usr/lib/python2.7 -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```

Change the directory as required. These commands won't produce any output if they succeed.

If you install modules in the normal way, though (using their `setup.py` script), you should never have to do this.

(I can't help you with Eclipse.)

Comment: I ended up needing a `sudo chmod -R a+r /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*` for good measure.

Comment: This works very well. Could anyone explain the {} \; syntax ?